# Pandas drop duplicated rows based on time gaps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thanks for helping out! I am collecting MAC addresses in my personal network. The output is saved as csv format. There are only two columns: MAC and TIME. The picture below should demonstrate my data file clearly:
[csv output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3802k.png)

What I am trying to do is find out whether any rows in the output has duplicates (based on MAC column). If yes then I will need to check the last two duplicates and see if there is a time gap of 1 hour or more. If again this returns yes then I will have to delete all duplicates of this MAC address from the output.

What I have achieved is finding the duplicates from the output csv however I can't go further than this because i have completely no idea where i can go from here.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!
What I have so far: (I tried to write a function and I call it the 'check list cleaner' which can be called at any time or maybe every minute in order to remove MAC address which was seen 1 hour or longer ago)

```
def CheckListCleaner(cList):  
cList[cList.duplicated(['MAC'], keep=False)]
dup = cList.tail(2)
for i in range(len(dup)-1):
    row1, row2 = dup.iloc[i], dup.iloc[i+1]
    if row2['TIME'] - row1['TIME'] >= 3600.0:
        #do something to remove rows
```

As you can see the function sure doesn't work. I tried to keep a list of duplicated MACs and compare the last 2 to determine whether certain MAC has been seen 1 hour or longer ago. however this doesn't work because I can have several duplicated MACs.

Sorry for the unclarity guys. So I added more pieces of my code so far. Below is the function I created to collect MAC addresses. Notice, I only want to collect transmitter MAC which belongs to 'addr2' from each type of packets

```
def BufferHandler(pkt):
if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.type == 0:
            bufferList.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 1 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            bufferList.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 2 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            bufferList.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 3 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            bufferList.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
```

As you can see the timestamps' format is strftime however I don't mind transfer them to other formats if necessary.

At the bottom of my code I run the sniffer like this:

```
while True:
print('check list creating on going')
checkList = CheckListCreator(args.iface, BufferHandler, 60)
CheckListCleaner()
```

My goal is to capture MACs until I manually stop the program. The 'CheckListCleaner' is what I try to build which should be able to check which MACs are seen more than 1 hour ago and remove them from the check list

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Post the content as text not image. (Format it as code

Comment: The image is to show my data outuput it is not code at all. just to give you a clear picture of what my csv look like

Comment: Rough idea, you can do something like [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) MAC address and then iterate each group with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) (make sure it should be sorted by time) and then just filter out the time differences between group by an hour and return the segment based on that. I am not sure what exactly the `time` format is, that's why just commenting.

Comment: I have just edited the question! The time format is 'strftime' for now

Answer (score 0):

My idea is as follows:

Your first condtion is the number of items per mac-address is larger than 1:

```
cond1 = df.groupby("MAC").count() > 1
```

The second one is that the last to items of each MAC-Adress differ by more than one hour:

```
cond2 = df.groupby("MAC").tail(2)["T"].diff() > pd.Timedelta("1h")
```

Now you can gat the combined condition:

```
combined_cond = cond1.mul(cond2)
```

Preparing for a merge:

```
combined_cond["M1"] = combined_cond.index
combined_cond.rename({"T": "val"}, axis=1, inplace=True)

out = df.merge(combined_cond, left_on="MAC", right_on="M1")
```

and finally selecting

```
out[~out["val"]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas! I understand most of your code however what do you mean by 'M1' here? I guess you just added a new column to the dataframe? I have also updated the question so maybe the extra information might be useful

Comment: sorry I am very new to both Python and Pandas. This may sounds silly but i am also confused with the '1' you use in both conds. In cond1 I get it, count()>1 means more than 1 entries but in cond2 you used the same expression, diff()>1. Can this 1 be used to represent 1 hour? i recall hour is written in seconds in Python . so something like 3600. I am very confused when or if i can use 1 to represent 1 hour.    btw, what does val refer to?

Comment: btw, I just tried out the code on a raspberry pi. i am keep getting error like this: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.  it seems to mean I am trying to subtract two string objects. the problem is on cond2. If you could check out the edited question i have tried using pkt.time only as the time output but in float format howeve the issue still exists

Comment: 'M1' is an arbitrary name for a column, reduced the name of MAC. afterwards I want to join the `df` and `combined_cond` by this column

Comment: Yes, I should find some alternative for `diff` it only works for numerics. Is your time column numeric. It seems like it is still some string like. Datetime objects are interpreted like strings in this function. So let's look for something else.

Comment: I finally found a solution for the correct usage of `diff`. The problem wasn't with the timestamps, but the diff is evaluated on the MAC-column, too.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot!!  my timestamp is in strftime format which is also a string format. it is also in the code i posted. I tried out the code on my raspberry pi however the error still exists. i still get the  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.   Regarding the parameters, did you use T for TIME?

Comment: Yes I used T for time. To be able to compare time you should go to pandas Dataframe.

Comment: sorry i don't think i follow here. pandas dataframe is used everywhere. all the data i am working with here are in dataframe. The code for cond2 doesn't work and I have tried different formats such as float